# How to navigate narrator focus to a non-focusable app on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, accessibility, narrator

I'm working on the input app, which doesn't have focus when users are typing. And users can't press "Alt" + "Tab" key to select it as it doesn't show in the running app list.

The problem is that I want to show some information to users when there are something happened. As input app doesn't have focus, sightless users can't navigate to input app to let narrator to read the content on input app. What is a good way of doing this?